# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una clase col-md-4 en Javascript a mis inputs dinámicos?

Tags: javascript, html, python, jquery, django

hice unos inputs en Django, funcionan bien, el problema se presenta cuando empleé Javascript, sucede que necesito que mis inputs generados dinámicamente tengan clases CSS, sobre todo necesito que tengan la clase col-md-4 para que no se vean enormes.

Para ilustrar el ejemplo, éstos inputs tienen el estilo y orden que deseo
[image: inputs que quiero hacer]

Al dar clic al botón de add, me generan los mismos inputs de arriba ya que se están clonando (sólo cloné 2 para hacer una prueba, posteriormente clonaré los demás inputs originales), si se dan cuenta están descuadrados, y no tienen las clases CSS para darle una mejor vista.

[image: inputs que me aparecen]

Alguien tiene idea de que puedo usar para solucionar éste problema? Agrego mi código en Javascript y en HTML. Gracias

```js
function addFormset() {
//take id total forms
let forms=document.querySelector('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS');

//create a div col-md-4 inside
//take id_form-0-representative and clone it
let newinput=document.querySelector('#id_form-0-representative').cloneNode(true);
//create new name with the current value
newinput.name='form-'+forms.value+'-representative';
//create new id with the current value
newinput.id='id_form-'+forms.value+'-representative';
console.log({newinput});
//take id_form-0-nameRepresentative and clone it
var newselect=document.querySelector('#id_form-0-nameRepresentative').cloneNode(true)
//create new name with the current value
newselect.name='form-'+forms.value+'-nameRepresentative';
//create new nameRepresentative with the current value
newselect.id='id_form-'+forms.value+'-nameRepresentative';
console.log({newselect});
//take representative formset's id and APPENDCHILD
//put new class name
newinput.className='form-control';
newselect.className='form-control';
document.querySelector('#Representativeformset').appendChild(newinput);
document.querySelector('#Representativeformset').appendChild(newselect);
forms.value=parseInt(forms.value)+1;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS">
<div class="row" id="Representativeformset">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
         <label>Representative</label>
         <input type="text" name="form-0-representative" class="form-control" maxlength="200" id="id_form-0-representative">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="form-0-nameRepresentative" class="form-control" maxlength="200" id="id_form-0-nameRepresentative">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
         <label>Department</label>
         <input type="text" name="form-0-department" class="form-control" maxlength="10" id="id_form-0-department">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
         <label>Phone Representative</label>
         <input type="text" name="form-0-phoneRepresentative" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-phoneRepresentative">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
         <label>Email Representative</label>
         <input type="text" name="form-0-emailRepresentative" class="form-control" maxlength="20" id="id_form-0-emailRepresentative">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
         <label>Notes</label>
         <input type="text" name="form-0-notesRepresentative" class="form-control" maxlength="200" id="id_form-0-notesRepresentative">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div id="FormsetContainer" class="col-md-4">
         <div class="mb-3 only-corp hide-item" id="onlyCorp">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" onclick="addFormset()">Add</button>
   <input type="text" name="form-1-representative" class="form-control" maxlength="200" id="id_form-1-representative"><input type="text" name="form-1-nameRepresentative" class="form-control" maxlength="200" id="id_form-1-nameRepresentative">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="submit" value="Post">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justo debajo de .appendChild, solo le añades las clases que quieras. Ejemplo: `newinput.classlist.add('laClaseQueQuieras');`

Answer (score 1):

la clase "col-md-4" la tiene la div en tu HTML, los inputs tienen clase "form control", probaste agregandoles esa clase?

Comment: sí ya les agregué, se ven bien los inputs de tamaño sólo que al darle click aparecen todos uno al lado del otro en la misma línea (row)